# Migração pro Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, heroku

Estou migrando o DB do meu `app` pro `Heroku`, o `deploy` funcionou:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Ao tentar migrar a base de dados de acordo com o comando `$ heroku run rake db:migrate` não funciona e retorna o seguinte erro:

> $ : No such file or directory

No log do `heroku` tem a seguinte entrada:

> ```
> > $ heroku logs
> > $ : No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
> ```

Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando abaixo localmente deve resolver o seu problema:

> rake rails:update:bin

Então tente fazer o deploy novamente.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23100542

Comment: valeu.  o problema mesmo era o ruby nã estar declarado no env. brigadão mesmo

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta como aceita?